# Как вы реализуете parallax эффект для устройств на ios (е)?

Tags: javascript, css3, веб-программирование, вёрстка, мобильная-разработка

Скажите пожалуйста - как вы реализуете parallax эффект для устройств на ios -(е) ?
Интересует Ваш - опыт!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону. На мобильных устройствах работает, в том числе и на safari

> http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: Алексей, Спасибо!